# Is it possible to access JSON properties with relative syntax when using JSON defined functions?

Tags: javascript, json, namespaces, this

```
// JavaScript JSON
var myCode = 
{
   message : "Hello World",

   helloWorld : function()
   {
     alert(this.message);
   }
};
myCode.helloWorld();
```

The above JavaScript code will alert 'undefined'.

To make it work for real the code would need to look like the following... (note the literal path to myCode.message)

```
// JavaScript JSON
var myCode = 
{
   message : "Hello World",

   helloWorld : function()
   {
     alert(myCode.message);
   }
};
myCode.helloWorld();
```

My question is... if I declare functions using json in this way, is there some "relative" way to get access to myCode.message or is it only possible to do so using the literal namespace path myCode.message?

Comment: `The above JavaScript code will alert 'undefined'. `   IT RETURNS 'Hello World' and not `undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example works, the `this` value inside the `helloWorld` function will refer to the `myCode` object itself, because you invoked it by `myCode.helloWorld();`

When you invoke a function that is member of an object, this object will be set as the `this` value of the function.

In this case `myCode` is the *base object* of the `myCode.helloWorld` reference.

There are two more cases about how the `this` keyword is *implicitly*, for example, when you call a function that is not bound as property of any object, i.e.:

```
myFunc();
```

The `this` value inside `myFunc` will point to the global object.

When you use the `new` operator:

```
var obj = new MyFunc();
```

The `this` value inside `MyFunc` will refer to a newly created object.

And you can set the `this` value of a function explicitly, using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply):

```
function test () {
  return this + " World";
}
test.call("Hello"); // "Hello World"
```

Just a note, *that's not [JSON](http://json.org/)*, JSON is simply a data interchange format, its grammar differs with the JavaScript [Object Literal syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_Object_Initializers), for example:

```
{ foo: "bar" }
```

The above is a valid JavaScript object literal, but is not valid JSON, JSON requires the property identifiers to be wrapped between quotes, and it has a limited set of data types allowed, for example, you cannot have *functions* as members of a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No.</strike>

First of all, this is not JSON.  What you have here is just an object literal.  JSON is a data format, and doesn't support functions.

Second, is an understanding of how **this** binding works.

Unless explicitly bound via [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Call) or [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/Apply) or used inside the method of an instantiated object, `this` always refers to the current `window` object.

Since you define `myCode` as an object literal, the "instantiated object" case doesn't apply.  Also, you aren't using `call()` or `apply()` so those don't apply either.  So in the code of your first example, `this` is equal to `window` which is why you get undefined (since `window.message` is undefined).

You already know one way around this - your 2nd code snippet.  Your other choice is to actually go ahead and use `call()` or `apply()`.

```
var myCode = 
{
   message : "Hello World",

   helloWorld : function()
   {
     alert( this.message );
   }
};
myCode.helloWorld.call( myCode );
```

This way, you are basically telling Javascript to use `myCode` as `this` and it will work as expected.

Another option is to make `myCode` instantiable.

```
var myCode = function()
{
  this.message = 'Hello World';
  this.helloWorld = function()
  {
    alert( this.message );
  }
}
var mc = new myCode();
mc.helloWorld();
```

Comment: No, `this` refers to the global object only when there is no *base object* in the reference being invoked, for example, `myFunc();`. In his example, the base object is `myCode` and it works,  `myCode.helloWorld.call( myCode );` is redundant.

Comment: That's what I get for posting after 3 beers. ¡Feliz Cinco de Mayo!

Comment: Count me in next time you drink beer

Answer (score 0):

CMS hit the nail on the head, if you want more info you could check out http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/chris/2010/05/what-is-this/